# Using iTunes gift code while temporarily staying in another country

Tags: itunes, gift

I am from Russia but currently stay in another country. I got an iTunes gift code as a present from a friend in Russia. Can I use this code while I'm in another country? I believe my Apple ID country is set to Russia.

Comment: If your Apple ID country is set to Russia, and your friend bought the codes from Russian Apple store, then yes, you can.